# Is there a word for someone being both 'Spectator and Participant'?

Tags: etymology, vocabulary

I was wondering if there is a single word for someone being 'both spectator and participant', as in "In the grand scheme of universe I am just another identity who is both a spectator and a participant". Observer (though not accurate) is a good replacement, but it is somewhat a common term. A more unique/fancy/special word would be desirable.

Thanks

Comment: Rotisserie player. e.g.: football rotisserie, Yahoo rotisserie, NBA rotisserie, etc.

Comment: I'm sure someone somewhere has used the word "specticipant" (not that I recommend it).

Answer (score 1):

If he is not playing and in your team you could call him a **teammate** or if you are a spectator and from a audience perspective he is not playing usually a sub or a reserve but he is still in the team so he can be called a **squad player**.

Answer (score 1):

Just conceivably, what you are talking about is the term coined by Alvin Toffler,

## **pro-sumption**

It means "production - by - consumers" ... that is to say, a business model where (bizarrely, really), the paying customers actually create the **pro** -duct.

Indeed, Toffler was staggeringly astute because, of course, many of the biggest and most famous businesses of our era -- Facebook, Youtube, Amazon's book reviews, Tripadvisor, etc etc -- are indeed "pro-sumption" businesses.

Indeed Stackoverflow is entirely a pro-sumption business, just like say Facebook.  The owners of SO make money and are able to buy diapers, food, etc, because (again - it's bizarre really!) us **consumers** of the site, rather incredibly, actually **make the product** (for free!)

There's a reasonably acceptable "wikipedia" article on it if you are not famiilar with the word: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prosumer

So it's just possible this is what you're after.

If you are talking more philosophically, or about Love or some other issue - you could actually use "prosumer" sort of humorously.  "We are all prosumers in the quantum universe" (I can't believe I just made up that sentence) or "In sexual relations, she was a prosumer, she generated all the heat she needed to take from a man." (Someone send me a harlequin cover quick!)

Just BTW I think the word is better with a hyphen, but it is usually spelled "prosumption" just like that.

Answer (score 1):

There is precisely such a word! It was coined by theater director Augusto Boal.  The word is *spect-actor*.  Boal's idea was to have spectators enter into the play they were watching to change its outcome.

Great word; I use it now on the time to talk about the engagement I would like from viewers; particularly   Applicable to students!